# Types missing from the "Member Types" section

Tags: bug, documentation

The following types are not listed on http://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=category#docs under the *Member Types* section:

- [`network_post`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/network-post)
- [`closed_details`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/closed-details)
- [`original_question`](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/original-question)

Note that it's a nonexhaustive ‎list, I'm adding types as I come across them.

Comment: I shamelessly recommend that you support [this feature request to allow users to edit the docs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/290167/allow-users-to-edit-the-api-documentation).

Comment: @Brock upvoted!